# Is there any simple library I can use to load common format images?

Tags: c, opengl, ubuntu

I want a image loader library to help me load images (bmp, jpg, gif, png, and other common format) in Ubuntu using C. I'm writing a opengl program and want to load image to textures. Is there any good choice?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/, might be overkill though.

Comment: If you use SDL, use SDL_Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about OpenCV?
This open source project already realise many algorithm and support C/C++ and python.
My classmates have done Object recognition project with OpenCV. easy to use~

Comment: I think for just loading textures, it's quite an overkill to bring dependency on OpenCV into the project.

Answer (score 0):

For simply loading images, OpenCV would be quite an overkill. I strongly recommend [DevIL/OpenIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/), which is a simple to use and small library that supports many image formats. It's especially suited to OpenGL applications, as the syntax and programming style is heavily oriented on OpenGL's.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend the SDL_Image library.  Plenty of simple functions for loading and displaying images in there.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [CAPI](https://github.com/b-sullender/CAPI) library. Lightweight and easy to use.